# Handling state and invalid-feedback attributes in BootstrapVue to reject deleted value in input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Having the next **BootstrapVue** sample code, I want to know how I can fix it in order to acchieve that the '***Mandatory field!***' message get displayed in the next secuence:

1. User writes a value or selects someone of the 'autocomplete' fruits suggested.
2. User delete whatever is in the input field.
3. User click the '***Test***' button.

Template:

```
<div>
  
  <b-form-group label="Fruit*" label-for="myInput" :invalid-feedback="invalidFruit" :state="stateFruit">  

    <b-form-input id="myInput" v-model="fruit" list="myList" :state="stateFruit"/>
        <datalist id="myList">
            <option v-for="fruit in fruits">{{ fruit }}</option>
        </datalist>
  
  </b-form-group>
  
  <b-button v-on:click="btnClicked=true">Test</b-button>
  
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      fruit: null,
      fruits: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Lemmon'],
      btnClicked: false
    }
  },
  computed: {    
        stateFruit() {
            var res = null;
            if (this.btnClicked) {
                res = (this.fruit != null || this.fruit == '');
            }
            return res;
        },
        invalidFruit() {
            var res = 'Mandatory field!';
            return res;
        },
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/u6j8m

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

change this line:

```
res = (this.fruit != null || this.fruit == '');
```

to this:

```
res = (this.fruit != null && this.fruit.length > 0);
```